# Quick question on inverse matrixes

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say we have $AC = I$,  both be an $m \times n$ matrix

we are given its inverse $A^{-1}$

Does it matter what order I multiply the inverse and $A$, for example

is: $$A^{-1}AC = AA^{-1}C = CI?$$

Comment: First of all $A$ and $C$ must be square matrices!

Comment: If A is $m\times n$ then C must be $n\times m$ for the multiplication to be possible (inner dimensions must agree). Also inverse is not defined for non-square matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$. So for multiplying $A^{-1}$ with $A$, order doesn't matter. But in general order matters as matrix multiplication is not commutative. For example if $B$ is a matrix different from $A$(or $I$ ), then $A^{-1}B\neq BA^{-1}$ in general.

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is not well defined for non square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

$A^{-1}$ is ambiguous when talking about non-square matrices so $A^{-1}$ does not even make sense. You can try and calculate **pseudo**-inverses, though.

1. If the columns < rows for $A$ then to solve the equation $AC = I$ a pseudo-inverse is the best you can do, because there can in that case never be enough information having been stored by $A$ to tell what an inverse should be doing.
2. In the other case where rows < columns for $A$ then to solve $AC=I$ there can be many or even infinite number of inverses.